# Phonegap to get user location with WiFi and mobile network not with GPS

Tags: javascript, cordova, wifi

I am building an android app in PhoneGap Cordova .I want to get the location of user from where the user is using my app.Is there any way to get the location of user if connected to **wifi** or **mobile network like GSM/CDMA 3G/H** ? **but not in native.**

Answer (score 0):

To request position using Wifi/mobile network but **not** GPS, set the `enableHighAccuracy` option to `false`.

e.g.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position){
    console.log("Accuracy is: "+position.coords.accuracy+"m"
  },
  function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  },{
    enableHighAccuracy: false
  });
```

See the [geolocation plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md) for more info.

Comment: **@ DaveAlden** -- It shows this message "**code : 2     message :  the last location provider was disabled**"

Comment: And is it possible to get the country ??